# How to check if name of an cells exists (name.name)?

Tags: excel, vba, named

I want to write the named area in a string (and go through column D unitl last row). But if the cell is not named I get an error on "Name = wsData.Cells(i, 4).Name.Name" and code is stopping there.

I need something like, if NamedArea is nothing/empty, then do next i.
Do you have an idea?

Thank you!!

```
    For i = 1 To LastRow

             Name = wsData.Cells(i, 4).Name.Name

        If UCase(arrData(k, j)) = UCase(Name) Then
                arrData(k, j) = arrNames(i, 1)
                x = x + 1
                k = 1
                j = 1
                i = 1

            Exit For
        End If

    Next i
```